# golang html/template ExecuteTemplate errant byte where is it coming from?

Tags: html, templates, go, lexer

**Background**
I was trying to write some GZIP middleware for Go, but ran into a problem as http.DetectContentType() was returning text/plain instead of text/html so I tracked it down to the first text being written was some sort or errant byte, that I am still trying to track down. I know there are lots of ways around it, like setting the ContentType explicitly or using a bytes.Buffer when Executing the template and writing all at once, but I really want to find out what is causing this single byte to be written.

**Example**
Here is a very contrived example that shows the same issue https://play.golang.org/p/SSrWP9jLRq

when run you will see the first thing that is printed is: "LEN BYTES: 1 String: "

**Suspects**
It appears, as the example shows, that this line "{{template "header" .}}" within the content template is the culprit, but why would it be outputting this extra content.

**Question**
Does anybody know where this errant byte is coming from? see the html header, footer and content templates in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because template content starts immediately following the closing braces in the define directive, the root, header and footer templates start with a newline.

The single newline is written at the start because the template flushes output before invoking a sub-template.

Change the definitions to start with

```
header = `{{define "header"}}<!DOCTYPE html>
...
content = `{{define "root"}}{{template "header" .}}
```

to eliminate the extra newlines. See https://play.golang.org/p/AzD98cD7c0 for a fix.

In Go 1.6 or latter, add a minus sign at the end of the action to trim whitespace following the action:

```
    header = `{{define "header" -}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
...

    content = `{{define "root" -}}
{{template "header" .}}
...
```

Add a minus sign to the beginning of the action to trim whitespace before for the action.

Comment: Thanks! Seems so silly now, I did try changing the header like you did but didn't even think to also make the change to the content.